# The keyboard doesn't show up in Textformfield

Tags: flutter, dart, keyboard

I have created a  textformfield that takes an input and then convert them to a chip like this in the picture

[image]

It doesn show the chip but then after the first chip input the keyboard wont pop up again
there isn't much to say about this problem thats all, also is this a good approach ? eventually i want the chips to be draggable such that i can rearrange them.
Please note: I dont want to use any package or plugin.This is all the code there is for now, you can try it in a dart pad or sth
here is the code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class FruitChip extends StatelessWidget {
  final String label;
  final bool isMatched;
  FruitChip({
    required this.label,
    this.isMatched = true,
  });
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Chip(
      label: Text(
        label,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: isMatched ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
    );
  }
}
class FruitForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FruitFormState createState() => _FruitFormState();
}
class _FruitFormState extends State<FruitForm> {
  final List<String> fruits = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Mango', 'Grapes'];
  final List<Widget> chips = [];
  final TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();
  void _addChip(String fruit, bool isMatched) {
    setState(() {
      chips.add(FruitChip(
        label: fruit,
        isMatched: isMatched,
      ));
      _textEditingController.clear();
    });
  }
  bool _isFruitMatched(String input) {
    for (String fruit in fruits) {
      if (fruit.toLowerCase() == input.toLowerCase()) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Fruit Form'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TextFormField(
            controller: _textEditingController,
            onChanged: (String value) {
              String trimmedValue = value.trim();
              bool isMatched = _isFruitMatched(trimmedValue);
              if (isMatched) {
                setState(() {
                  chips.add(FruitChip(label: trimmedValue));
                });
                _textEditingController.value = const TextEditingValue(
                  text: '',
                  selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: 0),
                );
              }
            },
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            maxLines: null,
            buildCounter: (BuildContext context,
                    {int? currentLength, int? maxLength, bool? isFocused}) =>
                null,
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 16.0,
            ),
            textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.top,
            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
            readOnly: chips.isNotEmpty,
            showCursor: true,
            cursorWidth: 2.0,
            cursorColor: Colors.blue,
            cursorRadius: Radius.circular(4.0),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
              hintText: 'Enter a fruit name',
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
              ),
              prefixIcon: chips.isNotEmpty
                  ? Wrap(
                      spacing: 8.0,
                      children: chips,
                    )
                  : null,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap body into SingleChildScrollView Widget

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    class FruitChip extends StatelessWidget {
      final String label;
      final bool isMatched;
      FruitChip({
        required this.label,
        this.isMatched = true,
      });
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Chip(
          label: Text(
            label,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
          backgroundColor: isMatched ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
        );
      }
    }
    class FruitForm extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _FruitFormState createState() => _FruitFormState();
    }
    class _FruitFormState extends State<FruitForm> {
      final List<String> fruits = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Mango', 'Grapes'];
      final List<Widget> chips = [];
      final TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();
      void _addChip(String fruit, bool isMatched) {
        setState(() {
          chips.add(FruitChip(
            label: fruit,
            isMatched: isMatched,
          ));
          _textEditingController.clear();
        });
      }
      bool _isFruitMatched(String input) {
        for (String fruit in fruits) {
          if (fruit.toLowerCase() == input.toLowerCase()) {
            return true;
          }
        }
        return false;
      }
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Fruit Form'),
          ),
          body: SingleChildScrollView(child:Column(
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                controller: _textEditingController,
                onChanged: (String value) {
                  String trimmedValue = value.trim();
                  bool isMatched = _isFruitMatched(trimmedValue);
                  if (isMatched) {
                    setState(() {
                      chips.add(FruitChip(label: trimmedValue));
                    });
                    _textEditingController.value = const TextEditingValue(
                      text: '',
                      selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: 0),
                    );
                  }
                },
                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                maxLines: null,
                buildCounter: (BuildContext context,
                        {int? currentLength, int? maxLength, bool? isFocused}) =>
                    null,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16.0,
                ),
                textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.top,
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                readOnly: chips.isNotEmpty,
                showCursor: true,
                cursorWidth: 2.0,
                cursorColor: Colors.blue,
                cursorRadius: Radius.circular(4.0),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                  hintText: 'Enter a fruit name',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                  ),
                  prefixIcon: chips.isNotEmpty
                      ? Wrap(
                          spacing: 8.0,
                          children: chips,
                        )
                      : null,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        );
      }
    }
```